# IN Robot Framework (Puppeteer Library), How do I enter a text on this iFrame

Tags: puppeteer, robotframework

IN Robot Framework (Puppeteer Library), How do I enter a text on this iFrame?

Using the Sample Source Below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad1ov.png)

My Sample Code is not working

```
Add Credit Card
    Sleep    5s
    ${expirycard}  Set Variable    '12/29'
    Click Element                                                   xpath://*[@id='cc_expiry']
    Input Text                                                      xpath://*[@id='cc_expiry']          ${expirycard}
    ${creditcard}  Set Variable    4111111111111111
    Input Text                                                      xpath://*[@id="pan"]     ${creditcard}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**

I must select the Frame first before I Input a text

```
Add Credit Card
    ${expirycard}  Set Variable    "12\/29"
    Input Text                                                      xpath://*[@id='cc_expiry']          ${expirycard}
    ${creditcard}  Set Variable    4111111111111111
    Select Frame                                                    xpath://iframe[@src='https://secure.tillpayments.com/iframes/pan.html']
    Input Text                                                      xpath://*[@id='pan']                ${creditcard}
    Unselect Frame
    ${cvv}         Set Variable    123
    Select Frame                                                    xpath://iframe[@src='https://secure.tillpayments.com/iframes/cvv.html']
    Click Element                                                   xpath://*[@id="cvv"]                ${cvv}
    Input Text                                                      xpath://*[@id="cvv"]                ${cvv}
    Unselect Frame
```